# Does NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI and NLS_COMP=BINARY make sense?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I hope this is not a dumb question:

I inherited a number of Oracle stored procedures, triggers, ... One of the triggers was written as follows:

```
create or replace trigger TRN_NIS_LOGON after logon on database 
begin
       execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'; 
       execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC'; 
end;
/
```

This caused issues. So, I read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm

Then, I was told is that I should just change the trigger as so:

```
create or replace trigger TRN_NIS_LOGON after logon on database 
begin
       execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI'; 
       execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP=BINARY'; 
end;
/
```

However, I do not think that makes sense. It seems to me that NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI/AI needs to be combined with NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC and the corresponding linguistic index. The goal is to make oracle behave like SQL server (I also skimmed through this: https://hoopercharles.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/sql-experimenting-with-case-insensitive-searches/).

It seems like the above trigger is a really bad idea and NLS_COMP and NLS_SORT must be set together, for a session, while working with tables that have linguistic indexes. A trigger like this should not be used. NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI without linguistic indexes will cause full table scans.  Is this correct?